# Can channel cause memory leak in clojure?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure, channel

Can the `go` block below cause a memory leak in Clojure if data is no longer put into `in` channel? Do i need to find a way to close the channel?

```clj
(defn printer
  [in]
  (go (while true (println (<! in)))))
```

Comment: This comment by the author of the `go` macro may contain the answer: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/clojure/xGWfw0O9kbU/mhJAhk-CbQEJ. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/29879996.

Answer (score 0):

Given there is no way for this `go` block to end, yes it will continue to use some extremely small amount of memory in the system to keep track of it. However as it's a `go` it will not consume a thread.

Comment: I don't think this is true. As a comment by glts remarks, parked goroutines are only kept around as long as there is some reference to the channel they're parked on. If the channel is garbage collected because nobody ever plans to write to it again, so will be the parked operations.